# How can I correctly put an image at the top of an ImageView having a specified height?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-image

I am absolutly a beginner in Android development and I have some problem positioning an image into an **ImageView** element of my layout. So I have the following situation, I have this **fragment** layout:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Dummy content. -->
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="0dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:src="@drawable/carbonara"/>
            <!--android:background="@drawable/carbonara" />-->

        <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1"
            style="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

So, as you can see in the previous code snippet I am setting a background image into an **ImageView** having an **height of 350dp** setted.

The problem is that the image height is less that 350dp and this is what I am obtaining:

[image]

As you can see in the previous screenshot what I obtain is that I have the 350dp **ImageView** (highlighted in blue) and the image is setted inside it vertically centered. I don't want that the setted image is vertically centerd but I want that it start at the top of the **ImageView**.

How can I implement this behavior? What am I missing?

I have tryed to change:

```
android:src="@drawable/carbonara"/>
```

with:

```
android:background="@drawable/carbonara" />
```

and in this way it fills all the **ImageView** space but in this way the image could appear deformed so I think that it is not a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to change in your layout and test again.

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

to

```
android:scaleType="fitStart"
```

See full [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) here

Comment: Tnx perfect, ant tnx for the documentation reference